# Issues whilst setting up remote development in PyCharm Professional

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm, jetbrains-ide, jetbrains-gateway

Was so excited to explore the "remote development" feature on PyCharm, since I don't have enough computing resources to run on my local machine.
Spent an entire day trying to set it up in multiple remote machines, but all of them failed.

**Approach 1** - let local IDE download remote IDE of the same version, failed with [logs](https://pastebin.com/heKA9LCQ) when I click on "Download and start IDE" option.

**Approach 2** - installed the tar.gz IDE of the same version on remote, extracted it, and then ran remote-dev-server.sh registerBackendLocationForGateway resulted in the following o/p.

```
'/home/<user>/.cache/JetBrains/RemoteDev/userProvidedDist/_scratch_<user>_pycharm_2022.2.4' -> '/scratch/<user>/pycharm-2022.2.4'
```

after which followed approach 1, it had detected the IDE that I had installed on remote, but failed again with [logs](https://pastebin.com/QRcBEtAw) when I clicked on "Open and start IDE".

How can I debug this? What else can I look into?